# How do I access a locally-running API in Expo / React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, expo, fetch-api

I am running an api (using fastAPI) on localhost:8000. When I try to use the Fetch API system, I get the following error:

`NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.`

This is on the web version of expo(http://localhost:19006/)

Below is the code:

```
const getProfile = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/profile', {
        method:'Get',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      });
      const json = await response.json();
      setData(json);
    } catch (error) {
      setErrorVal(error)
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
```

If I change out the fetch URL to something from https://dummy.restapiexample.com, I get no error. It seems I am having trouble accessing this API because it is local.

How can I access local API's using expo?